# libgdx - How Box2d body check if bullet position has reach target position?

Tags: libgdx, position, box2d, velocity, projectile

Here is the link below, how I move bullet to target position using touch point.
([Move a body to the touched position using libgdx and box2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477391/move-a-body-to-the-touched-position-using-libgdx-and-box2d))

My problem is how do I stop the bullet body, if bullet body has reach target position.

I already tried the below code, and its working properly.

```
PIXEL_TO_METER = 1/32.0f
time step = 1/45.0f, velocity iteration = 6, position iteration = 2
float distanceTravelled = targetDirection.dst(bulletPosition);
if(distanceTravelled >= MAX_DISTANCE){
   // stop
} else {
  // move body
}
```

but I want to stop the bullet on target position, nor on MAX_DISTANCE. But I have no  idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the bullet is **near** your target enough to say that it has reach target.

```
    float distance = targetPosition.dst(bulletPosition);
    if(distance <= DEFINED_PRECISION){
        // stop
        // also you can set the target's position to the bullet here
    } else {
        // move body
    }
```

Why **near** not **exactly** at the point? The bullet is going with some defined speed let say *10px per second*. If you have `60fps` that means that in every frame the bullet is being moved by *10/60px*.

If the bullet is starting with position `0` it's next position (in next frames) will be

```
1/6 (frame 1)
2/6 (frame 2)
3/6 (frame 3)
...
```

If target is at the position `1.5/6` you can see that although in `frame 1` bullet hasn't reached the target yet in the next fram **it has passed it** and it's like collision was never detected. That's why you need to define some precision. It's value should be at least of *1 frame step* so in this case it would be `1/6`

```
    float DEFINED_PRECISION = 1/6f;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, so if i'm using 1/45.0f time step. what is the defined_precision value?

Comment: also added question, in your example you are using targetPosition and not targetDistnce. Correct me if im wrong is the targetPosition already normalize?

Comment: target position is the position (vector) of the target not the direction that bullet is going to - what would be the reason for normalizing the position?

Comment: im getting the target position from touch input

Comment: ok so you should save the touch position as the target to some *Vector2* variable or just as *float x,y;* and this is your targetPosition

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, so if i'm using 1/45.0f time step. what is the defined_precision value?